next js nested route after resfresh css not working
I am building a website using Next.js in which I am using nested routes for dropdown. But there is a bug in it, when I go to the page and then refresh the page, it doesn't work.
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"/>
    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="me-auto navbar_show" >
            {/* about us */}
            <NavDropdown title="About" id="collapsible-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} href="/about">About Us</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} href="/about/news">News Letter</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} href={"/about/vision"}>Vision</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} href={"/about/mission"}>mission</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar.Toggle>

So anyone suggests how to fix this bug in Next.js and yes I use app directory.

hey, seems like your CSS styles are not applying to the pages properly. Have you imported your CSS (ex: globals.css file) in your layout file?

hello there,
thanks for your reply but i solve this issue..
It was found out after many research. i was use react bootstrap lib and i install but i am not import that's layout.js and And I used to import Personal in component which left to put in nested route. after import layout.js work properly
import '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

that issue solve my side i was use react-bootstrap and i use packge install but i'm not import in layout.js file. i am import personal files after update this and import layout.js all work..


import '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'



